# Treat local file as uploaded file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

Laravel 5.7. I have a class which I use to handle image uploads:

```
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image as ImageHandler;

class ImageUpload
{
    /**
     * Upload an image to the public folder
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile $imageFile
     * @return void
     */
    public function upload($imageFile)
    {
        $this->extension = $imageFile->extension();
        $this->filename = $this->getHashedFilename($imageFile);
        $this->originalImage = ImageHandler::make($imageFile->getRealPath())->encode();
        // Do other stuff...
        $this->saveImage();
    }
}
```

This works when passing an uploaded file to it. But I would like to reuse the code to also work with images stored on the filesystem. E.g. I have a placeholder image, which is stored in `resources/images`. I would like to pass it to the `upload` method of the `ImageUpload` class above. But my reference to the file is obviously a string, whereas the `upload` method expects an instance of `UploadedFile`. So when I try to do this:

```
class FooBar
{
    public function savePlaceholder()
    {
        $placeholderImage = asset('images/test.png');
        $uploadHandler = new ImageUpload();
        $uploadHandler->upload($placeholderImage);
    }
}
```

I get an error because I am passing a string rather than an instance of `UploadedFile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if `ImageUpload` is third party library class which you don't want to rewrite I see 2 options here:

1. Always check if you are passing instance of `UploadedFile` to `ImageUpload->upload()`. Convert it to `UploadedFile` if `string`.
2. Extend `ImageUpload` class and override `upload` function where you should do the same things described in option 1.

Comment: My problem is that if I do `$file = new UploadedFile($pathName, "test.png");` I get a `FileNotFoundException`, although the `$pathName` is correct.

Comment: I fixed by using `resource_path`